# Navigation with SSASideMenu in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I'm currently having a bit of an issue on how to do things right with navigation.

So basically my app looks like following:

[image]

I embedded the [SSASideMenu](https://github.com/SSA111/SSASideMenu%20%22SSASideMenu) like it was done in the Storyboard example on github.

The left-most View Controller and the empty one on the upper side get populated in code (like in the example ion github).
I can access the menu from the Tableviewcontroller (with the black rectangle in it)

What i want now is a way to navigate to five independent pages from the menu. From each of this pages i want to go back to my TableViewController( again the one with the black rectangle in it). PerformSegueWithIdentifier and all kinds of popViewController don't work,  because the MenuViewController isn't embedded in the Navigation Controller

So my question is, what would be the right way of doing things? A separate Navigation Controller for the menu? Or Embedding the menu in the existing one? Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats up to you. I recommend splitting it up into two storyboards to keep things seperate and clean. Its kind of clearer when you split it, because of a totally different "navigation section" in your hirarchy